# Cannot perform apt update CLOSED

Tags: ubuntu-19.04

I just installed Lubuntu 19.04 on a computer, everything went correct. But 3 days after that, the `apt update` command stopped working. I do not know what could be the causant of that.
This is my output running `apt update`:

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And this is my `sources.list` file.

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security multiverse
```

Can anyone say me how can i fix that? 
Obviously, I cannot install anything:

```
apt install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved in this way:

sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

grep -E 'archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 10):

You need to update your repository targets to the Eoan Ermine (19.10) release of Ubuntu. This can be done like so:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's|disco|eoan|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

Comment: It did not worked, same log as before.

Comment: This definitely works, note that this will upgrade your system the next time you run apt-get upgrade, which for me is a good thing